# CSpinButtonCtrl placing unwanted thousands separator period in buddy CEdit

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using a *CSpinButtonCtrl* to modify the integer value of a buddy CEdit. Nice at it is the *CSpinButtonCtrl* places a thousands separator period in the number once the value gets higher than 1.000. Problem is that MFC's Direct Data Exchange only reads the digits before the thousands separator so that 1.000 in the *CEdit* becomes 1 in the int that the value is exchanged with.

Right now I'm just checking the *CEdit* for a thousands separator period and comma every time it changes and then possibly remove it like this:

```
   //get current line from CEdit
   CString line;
   CEdit* pEdit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(nId);
   pEdit->GetWindowText(line);

   //replace periods and commas with nothing
   line.Replace(".", "");
   line.Replace(",", "");

   //Write the CString back to the CEdit
   pEdit->SetWindowText(line);

   //Set the cursor to the end of the line again
   pEdit->SetFocus();
   pEdit->SetSel(-1);
```

But that is obviusly somewhat hacky and gives wrong behaviour when a user enters a digit not a the end of the *CEdit*. The *CEdit* is already set to "numerical only" but that is either being ignored by the *CSpinButtonCtrl* or a thousands separator period or comma are tolerated as numerical.

Isn't there a way to simply turn that thousands separator period placement off? I dont need it anyway.

Comment: If only the digits before the decimal point are read to the integer variable, why do you need to manually remove the points? And wouldn't that change 1.000 to 1000, or it is the desired behavior(is the *period* a thousand separator)?

Comment: Exactly, the period is a thound seperator.

Comment: Oh language barrier, I'll fix my question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa313922%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) of `CSpinButtonCtrl`'s `create()` function:

> **dwStyle** 
>   Specifies the spin button control's style

And one of those style is:

> **UDS_NOTHOUSANDS**
>   Does not insert a thousands separator between every
>   three decimal digits.

so make sure your `CSpinButtonCtrl` has that style set to disable the thousand separators. You can probably do that from the Spin Button styles in the Properties [window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd91377e.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.